# "ADB Root access is disabled" Even with root access enabled

Tags: android, adb, root, lineageos

I'm trying to patch [Tingle](https://github.com/ale5000-git/tingle) on my Xiaomi Redmi 4A running on [LineageOS 17.1](https://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-4a/development/rom-lineage-os-17-1-unofficial-t4123973) via ADB for enabling system spoofing signature for microG. But I'm getting this error :`ADB Root access is disabled by system setting - enable in Settings -> System -> Developer options` everytime I type `adb root` in cmd (running as admin). My device is rooted with Magisk 20.4 and the 'Super Access' option is enabled as "Apps and ADB". I've also enabled "Android debugging" option under the 'Settings -> System -> Developer options'.

[image: [Screenshot Included]]

But I'm unable to find any option called 'ADB Root access' or 'Root Access' under 'Settings -> System -> Developer options'. I've also tried [abdb Insecure](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1687590) by Chainfire.

[image: Screenshot Included]

But with no luck, the problem still persist. I just want to get root access in my adb interface to be able to use Tingle.

Note : I'm on Android 10. My SELinux status is enforcing (not permissive) and my ROM isn't stock nor official.

Thanks in advance! Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @biAji pointed out, the 'Rooted debugging' option is not shown if `ro.debuggable` is set to 0 in the system props. The ADB as root option will be visible in developer options if you add the line `ro.debuggable=1` anywhere in the `/system/build.prop` file.

If you cannot edit the file as root but `su` is working in the adb shell or any terminal app then [SmartPack Kernel Manager](https://smartpack.github.io/spkm/) might be able to help. Install the app and go to the Build prop Editor section from the menu. If you can find a key-value pair `ro.debuggable` then edit its value to 1. If it doesn't exist then create a new prop with that name as key and the value as 1.

Now reboot the device and check if an ADB as Root option appears in developer options. If it does, the build.prop file was successfully edited and now you can uninstall SmartPack.

Answer (score 1):

After check the [source code](https://github.com/LineageOS/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/lineage-17.1/src/com/android/settings/development/AdbRootPreferenceController.java), this settings item will be available if the device is **debuggable**

```
    @Override
    public boolean isAvailable() {
        return Build.IS_DEBUGGABLE;
    }
```

And it's depend on the system props `ro.debuggable` which is set to 0 in my case.

I think I need a debuggable-boot image to patch the device.